# Add Scale Overlay template gxp OpenGeo suite sdk

Tags: boundless-suite, sdk, gxp

I need to add the scale on the map, it is assumed that .js is in the Widgets folder, that means that I should add as Plugin, maps and layers I have this code put in app.js:

```
map: {

id: "mymap", // id needed to reference map in portalConfig above

title: "Map"

items: [{

xtype: "gxp_scaleoverlay"

}]

I need you to visualize on the map, but does not work, I guess tools must put this code:

{
Ptype "gxp_ScaleOverlay"

  actionTarget "map.tbar"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At first, add a dependency to the header (app.js):

```
* @require widgets/ScaleOverlay.js
```

then within map section find `items:[]` and use this code:

```
{
        xtype: "gxp_scaleoverlay"
}
```

After this modification debug your application once more.